# in `initialize': string contains null byte Ruby

Tags: ruby, initialization

I wrote the following code on my desktop and it worked fine. I downloaded it on my laptop, downloaded ruby (v1.9.3), and tried to run it but got the following error. I'm pretty sure it has to do with Ruby being used for the first time but never got this problem on my desktop when I first ran Ruby.

```
C:/Users/Downloads/vscript.rb:18:in 'initialize': string contains null byte (ArgumentError)
from C:/Users/Downloads/vscript.rb:18:in 'open'
from C:/Users/Downloads/vscript.rb:18:in 'main'
```

Line 18 is the `File.open` line:

```
File.open("filename", "r") do |f|

  # Do while there are characters in the text file
  f.each do |line|

    # Checks to see if any parts in file match the regex and inform the user
    if x = line.match(/\d\.\d\.\d{4}\.\d/)
      puts "#{x} was found in the file."
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What encoding is `vscript.rb` in? UTF-16 perhaps?

Comment: It got encoded in UTF-8 without BOM

Comment: Are you certain that it is UTF-8? UTF-8 text shouldn't contain any zero bytes but UTF-16 will contain lots of zero bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. When I originally wrote the code the filename had /'s separating the folders. When I downloaded the file on my laptop, I copied its new directory from the address bar which uses \'s. Changed that and it works fine now.